# How to setup postgresql replication when installed on windows server 2016 servers

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, windows-server

I realize this is a basic question, and not very specific, but I don't know where to go for this.  I am being asked to deploy two web servers onto windows server 2016 onto two hosts for load balancing.  The database backend for the two web servers is PostgreSQL with POSTGIS.

I know how to install PostgresSQL.
I also know how to get them going for each host and attach them to their respective web servers.

What I don't know how to do is set them up for multi-master replication.  On windows.  All solutions I have found so far are Linux-based.

I'm looking for options and ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally never setup replication in a windows environment, working with PostgreSQL you're almost guaranteed some form of Linux environment.  That being said, I did find a blog that details how to setup replication between windows servers (read-only secondary).  This may not be a full solution for you but hopefully it will help.

https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/replicating-a-postgresql-database-in-a-windows-workstation/

Comment: I'll take it.  in this case it's also an ESRI box and my developers do not want to have it on linux.  Thanks much!